# Forming a polygon with classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, polygon

So, my problem is: I am trying to create a program which would create a polygon that has atleast 3 points(that are composed of coordinates x and y) or angles. I would like that, if there are less than 3 points or angles submitted, the program returns an error saying there are insufficient number of points. I need to create this with classes.

I have created this so far: `

```
class Polygon:

    number_points = 0
    number_angles = 0



    def __init__(self, coordinate_x, coordinate_y, angles):
        s = []
        self.coordinate_x = coordinate_x
        self.coordinate_y = coordinate_y
        self.angles = angles
        self.s = s.append([coordinate_x, coordinate_y])
        Polygon.number_points = Polygon.number_points + 1
        Nkotnik.number_angles = Polygon.number_angles + 1


    # Here i would like the program to check if there are enough points 
    # and angles to form a polygon and to check if all coordinates are 
    # numbers. If this requirement is not met, the program prints an 
    # error message.
    def creation(self):
        if not isinstance(coordinate_x, (int,float)):
            #raise Exception("That is not a number")
        if Polygon.number_points <= 3:

        `
```

The idea that I had is that i store the coordinates in a list and then when the user enters enough points, a polygon can be formed.

I am not a native speaker, so if I need to clear things a bit further feel free to ask :) thank you for any possible answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see an error here:

```
Polygon.number_points = Polygon.number_points + 1
Nkotnik.number_angles = Polygon.number_angles + 1
```

`Nkotnik` should be `Polygon`. Also, to make it shorter, you could do `Polygon.number_points += 1` and same for `number_angles`.

So now, the creation of the program:

```
def creation(self):
```

This is bad design. The function should take the number of points and the number of angles as parameters. So, do this:

```
def creation(self, points, angles):
```

But `creation` is basically `initialization`, so you should integrate it into your `__init__`.

Also, your `__init__` is strange. `number_points` and `number_angles` should be defined in the `__init__`, not the object body, because those variables are different for different `Polygon` objects. So after modification, your code looks like this:

```
class Polygon:
    def __init__(self, coord_list, angles):
        if len(coord_list) // 2 < 3:
            raise Exception("Side count must be 3 or more.")
        s = []
        self.number_points = 0
        self.number_angles = 0
        self.coordinates_x = coord_list[::2]
        self.coordinates_y = coord_list[1::2]
        self.angles = angles
        self.s = s.append([coordinate_x, coordinate_y])
        self.number_points += len(coord_list // 2)
        self.number_angles += len(angles)
num_sides = int(input('Number of sides: ')) #raw_input if you're using Python 2
points = []
angles = []
for i in range(num_sides):
    points.append(int(input('X value of point: ')))
    points.append(int(input('Y value of point: ')))
for i in range(num_sides):
    angles.append(int(input('Angle value: ')))
polygon_object = Polygon(points, angles)
```

And you're done!

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! what does this last line (polygon_object = Polygon(points, angles)) do? :D

Comment: @Jerfislav That creates a `Polygon` object and assigns it to a variable so you can access it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the check at creation time in the class, like this, also you need more that just a angle to define a point

```
import collections

PointCartesian = collections.namedtuple("PointCartesian","coordinate_x coordinate_y")
PointPolar = collections.namedtuple("PointPolar","magnitude angle")
#this is a easy way to make a class for points, that I recommend have
#a class too  

class Polygon(object):
    def __init__(self,*argv,**kargv):
        points = list()
        for elem in argv:
            if isinstance(elem,(PointCartesian,PointPolar ) ):
                points.append(elem)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Element "+str(elem)+" of wrong type")
        if len(points) <3:
            raise ValueError("Insufficient data")
        self.points = points
```

and in other place you have the routine that ask the user for the data, you can check every input or leave it to the class.

to call it do something like this

```
Polygon(PointCartesian(1,2),PointCartesian(4,7),PointPolar(5,28.2))
Polygon(*list_of_points)
```